# School address on DS-160

Tags: f1-visas, student-visas

I am filling out the DS-160 regarding the education part, and it is asking me for my school address. The address listed on the I-20 is the mailing address not the physical address, which one should I put, the physical address or the mailing one as listed on the I-20?